# Tridion 2011 what is the best way to extract all the unpublished pages/components

Tags: 2011, publishing

I need to extract all the products that are not published in Tridion 2011. How best I can extract these unpublished items?

Comment: get the items through Core Services using `UsingItemsFilterData',  loop through the items and you can look for `IsPublished` attribute to check if that is published or not.

Comment: Welcome to Tridion StackExchange @Nagesh It would help if you could give a bit more background to your question. Why do you want to do this? What have you tried already, etc. This helps other contributors to give high quality answers that will be useful for you and others.